# Error response from daemon: no such id in Jenkinsfile for uploading docker image to ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecr

I'm adding script in Jenkinsfile and trying to push docker image to ECR
The build was successful, but I got this error:

```
Successfully built xxxxxx
Error response from daemon: no such id: aaaaaa-tests:latest
```

I tried to modify the `docker push "${ecrHost}/${ecrRepo}"` by getting rid of "latest" but got the same error.

I'm not sure which step goes wrong, `docker tag` or `docker push`, very new to all of these stuff, can someone explain what's going on? Already messing around for a whole day now. Many thanks.

Comment: do your self a favor and add a `docker images` step to your build to confirm its been tagged properly.

Comment: @JoshBeauregard Hi can you be more specific? I don't understand..

Comment: after the `docker tag` line, before the push line insert a line `docker images` this will list all images on the local machine. there you will be able to see what was built and tagged.

It will give you some clue about whats going wrong. NOt a fix but a step for debugging.

Comment: I tried, it didn't show me the images, still the same logs @JoshBeauregard

Comment: can you paste the output with `set -ex`

Comment: @akskap I tried in cmd, it gave me error ```Environment variable -ex not defined```

Comment: @Cecilia I mean replace `set -e` in the script snippet that you've pasted above with `set -ex`. Also I'm not sure what is the value of ${label} here ? Secondly, the value of `ecrRepo` in your script is set to `aaaaa-tests` whereas you're building image with name `aaaaa`. So the daemon rightfully cannot locate your image

Comment: @akskap Hi I've made some changes and now it seems working now, I just got error for the last push step ```The push refers to a repository [xxxxx], denied: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/tr-jenkins-cluster/xxxx is not authorized to perform: ecr:InitiateLayerUpload on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:xxxx``` Does it mean I need permission in Jenkins or AWS?

Comment: You need to give the AWS role `arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/tr-jenkins-cluster/xxxx` the right to push to your ECR (`ecr:InitiateLayerUpload`) on the resource `arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:xxxx`, which you can configure in the IAM settings.

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann I used an existing role used to push image for another project, why the role works for that project but not this one? Is it because I didn't grant the permission for the new ECR repo? How can I grant the permission, add policy?

Comment: It's probably because the new ECR repository is not covered by your current policy. You can either attach a new policy or edit the existing one.

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann it's weird, I couldn't find this role in AWS, I actually didn't add any role in the jenkinsfile, I think Jenkins is using a role itself, how can I find out? ```denied: User: arn:aws:sts::3xxxxxxxx:assumed-role/xxx-jenkins-cluster/i-04xxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: ecr:InitiateLayerUpload on resource```

Comment: @Cecilia there should be a role attatched with jenkins instance, find out what all are the permission it has If no role is attached then create "IAM role" with ecr-access policy and attach with Jenkins server.  
This should work.

Comment: @anand I'm creating a role at the moment, it's just I'm wondering where I can find the arn for ECR repo, I've only found the ECR URL

Comment: @Cecilia your arn would be something like: "arn:aws:ecr:region-name:accountID:repositoryname".
But here I will suggest do not create a policy for repo specific, mark it as * so that it will allow pushing on any repo available in your ecr and you dont need to create multiple policies for multiple repo.

Comment: Hi I tried to modify the name several times ut still getting the same error, it gave me'denied' in policy simulator, ```arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:91111111:repository/aaaaa-tests``` or ```arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:911111111:repository/aaaaaa``` I tried both, all denied, any thoughts? @anand

Comment: @cecilia: create policy by providing * after the "accountid:" or attach the AWS managed ecr policy which has full access to ecr.

Comment: @anand ```arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:911111111*:repository/aaaaaa``` like this?

Comment: Commented as an answer. Try that way if not success than will discuss further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the all discussions the straight way is:
Step 1: create one IAM role
Step 2: attach the AWS managed policy which should be name of  `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess`with the IAM role
Step 3: attach the IAM role with the Jenkins instance

Now run the Jenkins job it should be able to succeed.

Comment: I've tested in policy simulator with the policy with full access ```{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:9111111114:repository/aaaaaa-tests"
        }
    ]
}``` But it still gave me an error

Comment: Please try the steps provided in answer, this will work

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been solved by editing the policy, it's really a pain...